# Tkinter - How to reset grid row configurations when switching to a different page

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have the following minimal program to describe my issue.

On running the code, one will get a start screen which has a *Welcome* Label (row=0) and a Login button(row=1). When one *Logs in* he/she will reach the home screen which has a Logout button (row=0) and a Textbox (row=1). I want **only** the home screen to be maximized (zoomed) and the Textbox to span the whole of vertical space so I set `grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)`.

The problem is, when one *Logs out*, the `grid_rowconfigure` configuration persists and the start screen is disfigured.

```
import tkinter as tk

class example(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        tk.Label(text='Welcome').grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Button(text='Login', command=self.home).grid(row=1, column=0)

    def home(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.attributes('-zoomed', True) #Full Screen
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        tk.Button(text='Logout', command=self.logout).grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Text().grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ns")

    def logout(self):
        self.attributes('-zoomed', False) #Back to original
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.start()

    def clear_widgets(self):
        for widget in self.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

example().mainloop()
```

I believe what I am asking is clear i.e. I want my original start screen back. So, is there a way to reset any such configuration or how should I go about doing this?

P.S. Changing the row of the Login button to say, 2, would solve my issue, but I believe that would be a hack.

Comment: I can't run your code: `_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm attributes window ?-alpha ?double?? ?-transparentcolor ?color?? ?-disabled ?bool?? ?-fullscreen ?bool?? ?-toolwindow ?bool?? ?-topmost ?bool??"`

Comment: @EthanField Well I don't have any such problems running it on my Ubuntu 18.04 using python3.6

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want to 'reset' ```grid_rowconfigure(x,weight=1)```. The easiest way to do that is by setting weight back to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On your main request. Since you want your original screen back, you will have to `.withdraw()` the window and recall it with `.deiconify()`
2. As Ethan Field said your code gives an error(same one he posted above). Don't know how you are able to run it, but I had to change your `self.attributes('-zoomed', True)` to `self.state('zoomed')` to make it work.

   ```
   import tkinter as tk

   class example(tk.Tk):
       def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.start()

      def start(self):
            tk.Label(text='Welcome').grid(row=0, column=0)
            tk.Button(text='Login', command=self.home).grid(row=1, column=0)

      def home(self):
            self.clear_widgets()
            self.state('zoomed') #Full Screen
            self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
            tk.Button(text='Logout', command=self.logout).grid(row=0, column=0)
            tk.Text().grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ns")

      def logout(self):
            #self.state('zoomed') #Back to original
            self.clear_widgets()
            self.withdraw()
            self.deiconify()
            self.start()

      def clear_widgets(self):
            for widget in self.winfo_children():
                 widget.destroy()

   example().mainloop()
   ```

Comment: Thanks Samuel. So basically, `deiconify` redraws the GUI i.e. everything is back to where it started, isnt it?

Comment: Also regarding the errors, I don't have any idea, but is it because of the version? I have tkinter 8.6

Comment: @Miraj50: no, deiconify doesn’t reset anything. It just makes a window visible.

Comment: @BryanOakley Then how does this code work? Surely the configurations are being reset, right? Also I removed the `withdraw()` function and kept only the `deiconify()` function. Still it works?! How is this happening?